# Integral of absolute value: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty {e^{-\frac{2}{b}|x - \mu |}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, absolute-value

I am stuck trying to integrate

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty {e^{-\frac{2}{b}|x - \mu |}}dx$$

Incidentally, I'm interested in solving equation (5) in [this](http://biocurious.com/files/histo-bin-size-scott.pdf) paper using the Laplace distribution. I just got stuck integrating an absolute value.

Comment: **Hint** The function is even in the variable $s := x - \mu$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**.  We have
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac2b|x-\mu|}\,dx
  =\int_{-\infty}^\mu e^{\frac2b(x-\mu)}\,dx
  +\int_{\mu}^\infty e^{-\frac2b(x-\mu)}\,dx\ ,$$
and I think you should find both of those integrals pretty easy.

Answer (score 2):

You may just perform the change of variable $u=x-\mu$, giving

> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac2b|x-\mu|}\,dx
>   =\int_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{-\frac2b|u|}\,du=2\int_0^\infty  e^{-\frac2bu}\,du=b.
> $$